# how to convert date time format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" to "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.sss" in r dataframe? second with fraction

Tags: r, timestamp, strptime

I am struggling to convert date time format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` to `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.sss"`  in an R `data.frame`? Note that I want seconds with fractional seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. You can format fractional seconds with e.g. `"%OS3"`.

From `?strptime`

> Specific to R is ‘%OSn’, which for output gives the seconds
>        truncated to ‘0 <= n <= 6’ decimal places (and if ‘%OS’ is not
>        followed by a digit, it uses the setting of
>        ‘getOption("digits.secs")’, or if that is unset, ‘n = 0’).
>        Further, for ‘strptime’ ‘%OS’ will input seconds including
>        fractional seconds.  Note that ‘%S’ does not read fractional parts
>        on output.

Example:

```
ss <- "2018-08-22 21:30:00.5"
format(as.POSIXct(ss, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "2018-08-22 21:30:00.500"
```

Or for a sample `data.frame`

```
df <- data.frame(
    date = c("2018-08-22 21:30:00", "2018-08-22 22:00:00", "2018-08-22 22:30:00"))
transform(df, new.date = format(
    as.POSIXct(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), 
    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3"))
#    date                new.date
#1 2018-08-22 21:30:00 2018-08-22 21:30:00.000
#2 2018-08-22 22:00:00 2018-08-22 22:00:00.000
#3 2018-08-22 22:30:00 2018-08-22 22:30:00.000
```

Comment: You're very welcome @BTB; please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer.